# For XML Explicit query putting one line outside of the tags

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I have a query that produces an xml document.  I have gotten all of it to work except for the fact that one line is outside of the xml tags.  Any idea of why this could be?  Am I missing something? Edit- Also I notice that the last variable is missing all together.

This is the query that produces the xml...

```
    select
    1 as tag,null as parent,'' as 'labels!1',
    'SPICE ZEBRA LPN' as 'labels!1!_FORMAT',
    'ProductionLabel' as 'labels!1!_JOBNAME',
    1 as 'labels!1!_QUANTITY', 
    @printer as'labels!1!_PRINTERNUMBER',
    '' as 'label!2',
    null as 'variable!3','seq' as 'variable!3!name',
    null as 'variable!4','day_n' as 'variable!4!name',
    null as 'variable!5','bottom' as 'variable!5!name',
    null as 'variable!6','JOB_NUMBER' as 'variable!6!name',
    null as 'variable!7','desc2' as 'variable!7!name',
    null as 'variable!8','part' as 'variable!8!name',
    null as 'variable!9','DESCRIPTION' as 'variable!9!name',
    null as 'variable!10','INPUT_QTY' as 'variable!10!name',
    null as 'variable!11','QTY_LABELS_TO_PRINT' as 'variable!11!name'
    union all
    select
    2 as tag,1 as parent,'','1','','','','',
    seq ,'seq',
    day_n ,'day_n',
    bottom,'bottom',
    JOB_NUMBER,'JOB_NUMBER',
    desc2,'desc2',
    part, 'part',
    DESCRIPTION,'DESCRIPTION',
    INPUT_QTY,'INPUT_QTY',
    QTY_LABELS_TO_PRINT, 'QTY_LABELS_TO_PRINT'
    from cte
    union all
```

And this is what the output looks like...

```
    <labels _FORMAT="SPICE ZEBRA LPN" _JOBNAME="ProductionLabel" _QUANTITY="1" _PRINTERNUMBER="4">
    <label>
    <variable name="seq">1</variable>
    <variable name="day_n">Tuesday</variable>
    <variable name="bottom">Date:Oct 27 2015, Factory:88, Area:1DRY</variable>
    <variable name="JOB_NUMBER">433112</variable>
    <variable name="desc2">500425 (Frz Cosi Turkey Chili Soup - Bulk)    </variable>
    <variable name="part">Order:*, Part:100699, Name:Base, Turkey (JMH)    </variable>
    <variable name="DESCRIPTION">Mix With Bean Water</variable>
    </label>
    <variable name="INPUT_QTY">52.199994000000</variable>
    <label>
```

Can Anyone tell my why INPUT_QTY is outside of the label tags?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 'INPUT_QTY' as 'variable!12!name' - Based on your naming scheme, shouldn't this be 'INPUT_QTY' as 'variable!10!name'

Comment: Yes, thank you, I was switching things around to see if they worked and forgot to change it back.  It is fixed now.

Comment: But it still gives the same errors.

Comment: Do you have a reason not to use `FOR XML PATH`? This `EXPLICIT` is quite horrible to write... If you poste your expected output (the XML as it should be), I could give you an example...

Comment: Did you post the entire query? I'm not able to get your query to return the output you stated. Moreover, the tag/parent references don't look quite right. I have a feeling we'd need to see the entire query (assumption due to UNION ALL at the end).

Comment: etliens, No I did not add the entire query, just what was pertanent.  The union all just adds the same things 10 times. Shnugo, I didn't use FOR XML PATH because this is the query I have inherited.  I added a few things to it but being a novice at xml writing I didn't know if FOR XML PATH would give me the results I'm looking for.

Comment: Etliens, After reading your comment I went through my unions. I noticed I was missing a tag, also noticed one was saying parent was 1 not 2, hence the reason it was showing outside.  Thanks for your help everyone.  It's always the little things.

Comment: Hi Andy, found this only by incidence... You must add the `@` sign to the user's name. The addressed user will be notified. I could show you an example of `FOR XML PATH`, if you poste the expected XML (the output you want to get). This syntax is much easier and more comfortable than ÈXPLICIT`